# How to take part of the vector which is an output of neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

If I have a neural network built in `tensorflow 1.x`, the output is a vector Y,  I need to take the values of `Y(1:4:end)` (This notatation is in MATLAB) whith is equivalent in python to `Y[0:len(Y):4]`. But, when I perform that way, I get at error as follows:

```
raise TypeError(_SLICE_TYPE_ERROR + ", got {!r}".format(idx))
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(8)])
```

This means as I think it's not valid to use the same command for the output of NN which is called tensors.  So, how can I do that for that vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
len(Y)
```

is returning a TensorShape object, rather than an int.

Can you try:

```
Y[0:tf.size(Y):4]
```

To get the number of elements in the tensor.

You can also try:

```
Y[::4]
```

to index every 4th item in the list/array

Comment: @Gze no worries, please press 'answered' to close the question :)

Comment: yes, it says I can accept the answer in three minutes.